# How do I set up dev environment with buildkit?

Tags: developer, civicrm-buildkit, mamp

I am new to the developer/code side of CiviCRM and attending the Dev training at CiviCON. [I saw a post on StackOverflow about installing buildkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575021/install-civi-buildkit-to-have-a-working-civicrm) but haven't seen it re-posted here. I would appreciate a little more detailed steps on installing buildkit so I am prepared for the training.

I am using a Mac and it has also been recommended to me that I use [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/). Would I install buildkit inside MAMP?

Answer (score 15):

As Kurund pointed out, the general instructions are at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit . Follow those instructions to download the all the tools.

There are a few details that may not be well represented yet in the documentation:

1. As the main developer behind buildkit, I use it mostly in MAMP (and a bit in Debian and Ubuntu).
2. Buildkit runs several things on the command-line, so you need to make sure that the command-line is setup with the right version of `php`. By default, OSX uses its built-in version of `php`, but MAMP's version is generally better. See: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Setup+Command-Line+PHP
3. I suggest putting buildkit in your home directory (e.g., `git clone https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit.git ~/buildkit`). This is where all the *tools* will go. The source-code for CMS+Civi may go somewhere else (more in a moment).
4. After downloading buildkit, you'll need to setup a site with Civi. You can choose among two distinct workflows:

   - `gitify`: You install CMS+Civi manually and then run `gitify` to load the bleeding-edge Civi code.

     - *Where*: You can put the code anywhere. In MAMP, `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs` is probably easiest.
     - *Pro*: You can use any tools or processes you want to setup Apache, MySQL, CMS, etc.
     - *Pro*: Your configuration is custom. You control everything directly.
     - *Con*: Your configuration is custom. It's hard for other developers to reproduce, and it doesn't match the official test/demo environments.
     - *Con*: If you need to create multiple sites, you have to do all setup work repeatedly.
     - *Con*: If you want to work with the [automated tests](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Testing) or schema, then you'll need to do several extra configuration steps.
     - *Summary*: `gitify` is generally best for light development with a single build.
     - *Next step*: Setup Apache+MySQL as you normally would. Install a CMS (Drupal/WordPress) and CiviCRM using tarballs or zip files. Then, run `gitify` with no arguments. It will display a help screen with some examples.
   - `civibuild`: You run a command like `civibuild create d46 --url http://d46.localhost`; the command automatically configures Apache+MySQL, downloads Drupal, downloads Civi v4.6, and installs them.

     - *Where*: All builds will get placed under  buildkit's folder. For example, the "d46" build might be `~/buildkit/build/d46`.
     - *Pro*: Setting up new sites is automated. It's easy to create several different sites using a mix of CMS's and versions.
     - *Pro*: Your configuration is standardized. It matches the official test/demo environments.
     - *Pro*: Each site is automatically configured to run the [automated tests](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Testing).
     - *Con*: Your configuration is standardized. Loading things to match your personal preferences requires more work.
     - *Con*: The upfront configuration can be difficult/unforgiving - buildkit needs access to the internals of Apache and MySQL. Generally, it's based on a philosophy of "fail early, fail hard".
     - *Summary*: `civibuild` is generally best for heavy development.
     - *Next step*: See the detailed tutorials at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit/blob/master/doc/civibuild.md or https://buildkit-ui.civicrm.org/#/welcome .
5. If you go the `civibuild` route, then will need to prep the system by running `amp config`, which will present some questions and instructions for the local system. In a default MAMP configuration, some good values are:

   - `db_type`: `mysql_dsn`
   - `mysql_dsn`: `mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:8889` (or sometimes `:3306`)
   - `perm_type`: `osxAcl` (or `none`)
   - `perm_user`: `www`
   - `hosts_type`: `file`
   - `httpd_type`: `apache`
   - `httpd_restart_command`: `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl graceful`
6. In any workflow, buildkit has better support for Drupal- or WordPress-based dev-sites. There's some experimental code to support Joomla-based dev-sites, but the Civi-Joomla installer is difficult to automate, and it probably won't be resolved until http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35050.0.html gets some real attention.

Answer (score 3):

Using MAMP should be fine. You might also have to install git. For detailed instructions on buildkit please check:

> https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit
>
> https://buildkit-ui.civicrm.org/#/welcome

Answer (score 0):

Point 6 above perhaps explains why Joomla seems to be getting less support than Drupal or WordPress.  I have a local Joomla environment, but it is probably not correctly configured for development.  I was trying to improve that environment, but couldn't find instructions as to how to do it in Joomla.