# What's the quickest way to set up a developer environment on windows?

Tags: civicrm-buildkit

Wondering how to set up a dev environment with buildkit on Windows with the least amount of pain. Is there a shortcut like a prepackaged virtual machine image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you also need bash, it MIGHT be doable with cygwin (https://www.cygwin.com/), but I think it would be a considerable amount of pain.

The least pain imo would be: install Virtualbox, install Ubuntu on it and then follow [How do I set up dev environment with buildkit?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/635/how-do-i-set-up-dev-environment-with-buildkit)

Comment: Nice one :-) But I guess the objective is not really met if I tell Windows to pretend it is Ubuntu :-)

Comment: well, he did ask for the least amount of pain and he did mention a VM. buildkit needs bash. You can easily run CiviCRM on windows, but not buildkit.

Answer (score 2):

Start with WAMP:

http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Windows, Apache, mySQL, PHP

Answer (score 1):

I expect the WAMP stuff would be pretty straightforward as Kalanh suggests. But doing a buildkit might throw up some issues...I already get some issues on my Ubuntu machine, let alone Windows :-)