# Using buildkit on MAMP but hitting "Fatal error: Call to a member function getDriver() on null"

Tags: civicrm-buildkit, mamp

I am trying to install buildkit on a Mac with MAMP, but am hitting this wall:

> **Fatal error: Call to a member function getDriver() on null in phar:///Users/user/buildkit/bin/amp/src/Amp/Database/MySQL.php on line 58**

What am I missing?

I have been following the [buildkit readme](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit) and have gone through [this thread about setting up with MAMP](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/635/how-do-i-set-up-dev-environment-with-buildkit/639#639) but am not sure where I went wrong because I get the error when I actually try to use it.

```
MacOSX:dmaster.localhost user$ civibuild create dmaster
[[Download dmaster (type 'drupal-demo' in '/Users/user/buildkit/build/dmaster')]]
Already downloaded dmaster
[[Install dmaster/default (type 'drupal-demo' in '/Users/user/buildkit/build/dmaster')]]
[[Execute /Users/user/buildkit/app/config/drupal-demo/install.sh]]
++ source /Users/user/buildkit/app/config/drupal-demo/install.sh
+++ amp_install
+++ _amp_install_cms
+++ echo '[[Setup MySQL and HTTP for CMS]]'
[[Setup MySQL and HTTP for CMS]]
+++ cvutil_assertvars _amp_install_cms CMS_ROOT SITE_NAME SITE_ID TMPDIR
+++ _cvutil_assertvars_back=ehxB
+++ set +x
++++ mktemp.php ampvar
+++ local amp_vars_file_path=/Users/user/buildkit/app/tmp/ampvar3Oj48j
+++ local amp_name=cmsdefault
+++ '[' default == default ']'
+++ amp_name=cms
+++ '[' -n http://dmaster.dev ']'
+++ amp create -f --root=/Users/user/buildkit/build/dmaster --name=cms --prefix=CMS_ --url=http://dmaster.dev --output-file=/Users/user/buildkit/app/tmp/ampvar3Oj48j --perm=admin
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getDriver() on null in phar:///Users/user/buildkit/bin/amp/src/Amp/Database/MySQL.php on line 58

Fatal error: Call to a member function getDriver() on null in phar:///Users/user/buildkit/bin/amp/src/Amp/Database/MySQL.php on line 58
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may indicate that either:

- The PHP runtime is missing the PDO or MySQL extensions.  This may help: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Setup+Command-Line+PHP (At time of writing, I'd avoid PHP 5.6 for CLI dev -- GenCode may have issues with it.)
- The DB settings haven't been configured (e.g. the step for running `amp config` was skipped).
- An incompatible or incorrect value was used in the DB settings.

For reference, I believe these are the settings for use with a typical MAMP. (Note: The line is long.)

```
amp config:set --db_type=mysql_dsn --mysql_dsn='mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306' --httpd_type=apache --httpd_restart_command='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl graceful' --hosts_type=file  --perm_type=osxAcl --perm_user=www
```

However, if you didn't run `amp config` before, it's still good to run it to see more complete instructions (esp. regarding `httpd.conf`).

Comment: Thank you! I had skipped over the 'amp config' step somehow. Past this error now and trying to stagger through some other issues. ;)