# How to actually open a civibuild demo site in MAMP Pro?

Tags: civicrm-buildkit, civibuild, mamp

Okay, I feel like a real dummy, but I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

I'm on MacOS Monterey, MAMP PRO 6.6.2.  I finally got BuildKit fully installed and functioning [following these instructions.](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/635/how-do-i-set-up-dev-environment-with-buildkit)

A quick aside for other people who may find this, I got hung up for a few hours when **amp test** reported it was blocked on port 8888. I tried all kinds of things I found online, including changing ports in MAMP, editing httpd files, etc. What eventually worked for me was a fresh install of MAMP PRO + running **sudo killall httpd**.

civibuild now works as expected and I am able to create demo sites under ~/buildkit/build.

But now I have no idea how to get these sites open...

- MAMP Pro is currently set up with default settings, so it's looking
  at ~/Sites. I've tried adding a host with a document root outside of ~/Sites, but that doesn't seem to work. This may be a permissions issue... although I've granted MAMP Full Disk Access.
- I've followed the MAMP PRO documentation to add a "custom" host that imports the ~/buildkit/build/new-demo-site/web content as a "template," but that doesn't work.
- When creating the site with civibuild, I tried setting the url of the new site to be http://new-demo-site.localhost. Then I tried turning on the servers in MAMP, popping that url into Chrome, but all I get is the index.php file that's in the ~/Sites/localhost folder that MAMP PRO generates on setup.

I feel like I have to be missing something so basic that no one's felt the need to explain it. Either that or I'm simply not typing the right keywords into my searches.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it!